# How to access values from a table using dictionary and array functions in C#

Tags: c#, arrays, dictionary

I'm trying to write some code in C# which allows me to access values from the table below after providing the following inputs:

[image: table]

- ground (Rock, Stiff soil, Soft soil)
- moment magnitude (6.5, 7.5, 8.5)
- source_to_source (0-20, 20-50, 50-100)

I've tried with the following code but keep getting the message:

> System.Collections.Generic.KeyNotFoundException occurred – ‘The given key was not present in the dictionary’.

Could anyone help me to get it to work? Is there a more efficient manner in which I could write this code?

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace _20180607_dict_example1
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {                            
            string ground = "Rock";
            string moment_magnitude = "6.5";
            string source_to_source = "0-20";            
            double ratio_peak;
            int first_value;
            int second_value;
            int third_value;                

            // 0b. Calculate ratio peak from Table 2 in Hashash paper

            var valueDict = new Dictionary<string, int> { { "6.5", 0 }, { "7.5", 1 }, { "8.5", 2 }, { "rock", 0 }, { "stiff soil", 1 }, { "soft soil", 2 }, };

            if (valueDict.ContainsKey(moment_magnitude))
            {
                first_value = valueDict[moment_magnitude];
                Console.WriteLine(first_value);
            }

            if (valueDict.ContainsKey(ground))
            {
                second_value = valueDict[ground];
                Console.WriteLine(second_value);
            }

            int[,] array = new int[3, 3] { { 0, 1, 2 }, { 3, 4, 5 }, { 6, 7, 8 } };

            Console.WriteLine(array[valueDict[ground], valueDict[moment_magnitude]]);

            var valueDict_source_to_source = new Dictionary<string, int> { { "0-20", 0 }, { "20-50", 1 }, { "50-100", 2 } };

            if (valueDict_source_to_source.ContainsKey(source_to_source))
            {
                third_value = valueDict_source_to_source[source_to_source];
                Console.WriteLine(third_value);
            }

            int[,] ratios = new int[3, 9] { { 66, 97, 127, 94, 140, 180, 140, 208, 269 }, { 76, 109, 140, 102, 127, 188, 132, 165, 244 }, { 86, 97, 152, 109, 155, 193, 142, 201, 251 } };

            Console.WriteLine(ratios[valueDict_source_to_source[source_to_source], array[valueDict[ground], valueDict[moment_magnitude]]]);

            ratio_peak = (ratios[valueDict_source_to_source[source_to_source], array[valueDict[ground], valueDict[moment_magnitude]]]);

            Console.WriteLine(ratio_peak);

            Console.ReadKey();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Your dictionary has a key of `rock` but your `ground` variable is `Rock`. They need to be the same.

Comment: Can you not instead use `double moment_magnitude = 6.5` and then set `valueDict = new Dictionary<double, int> ...`?

Comment: @ataraxia in the OP's code, the dictionary's keys also contains `"rock"` - how would that work with a `Dictionary<double, int>`? Although I do think that representing doubles as strings is not a good idea - probably having two separate dictionaries would be the best way to go.

Comment: @MattJones my bad, I missed that. Depends on OP's application as to how they can process strings and doubles so up to them.

Comment: @dazedandconfused did you want a fix for your exception? or a better approach?

Comment: I've found a fix now thanks. I was just wondering if there was a better approach for me to write the code in the future so that I can improve my programming skills.

Answer (score 2):

Here is an idea using a more object oriented approach.

First, you create a class that represents each record, for example:

```
public class Surface
{
    /// <summary>
    /// Name of the surface e.g. RockA
    /// </summary>
    public string Name { get; set; }

    /// <summary>
    /// Moment magnitude Mw
    /// </summary>
    public double Moment { get; set; }

    /// <summary>
    /// Source to site distance from 0 to 20 km
    /// </summary>
    public int SourceToSite20 { get; set; }

    /// <summary>
    /// Source to site distance from 20 to 50 km
    /// </summary>
    public int SourceToSite50 { get; set; }

    /// <summary>
    /// Source to site distance from 50 to 100 km
    /// </summary>
    public int SourceToSite100 { get; set; }
}
```

Then you create a list of them, make sure the name of the surface is the same for each group, for example, RockA:

```
List<Surface> surfaces = new List<Surface>();
surfaces.Add(new Surface
{
    Name = "RockA",
    Moment = 6.5,
    SourceToSite20 = 18,
    SourceToSite50 = 23,
    SourceToSite100 = 30
});

surfaces.Add(new Surface
{
    Name = "RockA",
    Moment = 7.5,
    SourceToSite20 = 43,
    SourceToSite50 = 56,
    SourceToSite100 = 68
});

surfaces.Add(new Surface
{
    Name = "Stiff soil",
    Moment = 6.5,
    SourceToSite20 = 35,
    SourceToSite50 = 41,
    SourceToSite100 = 48
});

[...]
```

Now you can access the data more easyly, for example, using Linq queries:

To obtain all records with the surface "RockA":

```
List<Surface> rocks = surfaces.Where(x => x.Name == "RockA").ToList();
```

Surfaces with moment = 6.5:

```
List<Surface> magintude65 = surfaces.Where(x => x.Moment == 6.5).ToList();
```

Source to distance between 25 and 55

```
List<Surface> result = surfaces.Where(x => x.SourceToSite50 >= 25 && x.SourceToSite100 <= 55).ToList();
```

If you don't want to create a class, you can also use a list of Tuples:

```
var surfaces = new List<Tuple<string, double, int, int, int>>();
surfaces.Add(new Tuple<string, double, int, int, int>("RockA", 6.5, 18, 23, 30));
[...]
```

Then you can make the same kind of queries but I recommend you use a class, this is what they are for, anyway.

Answer (score 1):

By default, Dictionaries with String keys use the default String comparer, which is case sensitive. Your code will work if you change the ground variable value to "rock" instead of "Rock".

Comment: additionally the OP could use StringComparer.InvariantCultureIgnoreCase when making the dictionary as well.  Then case wouldn't matter.